# Reversing the order of notifications in the notification bar of a given app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, notifications, 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, whatsapp-messenger

I have a Galaxy S1 (I9000) running SlimRom (Android 4.2.2).

The problem I have is the following:

Assume someone sends me 3 messages in whatsapp (this is case important to me, but the problem is in general): First he sends 'a', then 'b', then 'c'.

The way I see the notifications is, from top to button, is 'c','b','a'.

I realize this is caused by the stack like implementation of the notifications, but since I read top-down I would like to see it as 'a' at top, then 'b', and finally 'c' at the bottom.

I recall that with the latest CM10 I had (also Android 4.2.2) they actually fixed this problem, but I am happy with SlimRom and I don't want to change my Rom solely on the sake of this problem.

Is there anything I can do about it ?